# You do not have any administrative items [Drupal]

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am getting below error in Drupal 7 when I try to open the admin panel. I have checked the database, the user I am logging in with exists and is the admin and has the the privilege to see the admin panel,

> you do not have any administrative items

Comment: I will assume you are visiting the "/admin" url. This page will display links to other admin pages (controlled by their own permissions). Give the user/role the permission to "Administer content" and you should get a "Content" link on that page which directs to "/admin/content"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more in the php error log?

**Maybe this will help:**

- https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2012-01-29/you-do-not-have-any-administrative-items-fixed
- https://languor.us/drupal-7-and-you-do-not-have-any-administrative-items-error